# Error Code: 1143 SELECT Command Denied Whenever I try Running an Update Query, even Though I Have Both UPDATE and SELECT permissions

Tags: mysql

I get Error Code: 1143. SELECT command denied to user whenever I try to run an UPDATE query with a condition statement.

I have SELECT permissions on all tables in the database, and UPDATE permissions on certain fields in certain tables.

`` GRANT SELECT ON `Base`.* TO `php_role`; ``

`` GRANT UPDATE (`amount`) ON `Base`.`cart` TO `php_role`; ``

I am able to run the following SELECT query without any errors:

`` SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `subscription_id` = 0; ``

but when I try running an UPDATE query, I get the error:

`` UPDATE `cart` SET `amount` = 0 WHERE `subscription_id` = 0; ``

Even if I grant myself UPDATE permissions on the entire table, I still get the error.
The only I found to fix it, was by granting UPDATE permissions on the entire database.

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

As Root, create the database, table, and user

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
USE test_db;

CREATE TABLE test(
    p_id INT,
    val INT,
    
    PRIMARY KEY(p_id)
);

CREATE ROLE test_role;
CREATE USER test_user IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT SELECT ON test_db.* TO test_role;
GRANT INSERT ON test_db.* TO test_role;
GRANT UPDATE (val) ON test_db.test TO test_role;

GRANT test_role TO test_user;
SET DEFAULT ROLE test_role TO test_user;
```

As the newly created user, login and try running an UPDATE query

```
USE test_db;
UPDATE test SET val = 0 WHERE p_id = 0;
```

The UPDATE query results in the error, while the following query works fine:

`SELECT * FROM test;`